# PostgreSQL: Import CSV file not containing id primary key

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a big CSV file like below:

```
psql -U postgres -d opendata -c " \
  COPY foos \
  FROM '/tmp/foos.csv' \
  DELIMITER '|' \
  CSV \
  HEADER"
```

But it doesn't contain the first `id` column of my table.

How should I better deal with it ?

Is there an option to autofill this column ?
Should add add the id at the beginning of each line of my file ?

Comment: Is the `id` column in the table some form of autoincrement, say `serial` or `identity`? If it is you don't to need to add the actual `id`, just an empty column. For example: `|second_val|third_val|...`. The lack of a value will cause the `id` autoincrement to fill in the value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver default value for `id` is `nextval('foos_id_seq'::regclass)`, but after adding empty column for it, I'm getting `ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "foos" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: My mistake, an unquoted empty value in `CSV` will be taken as `NULL`.  Per this [suggestion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20220212215702.shdf2pmoshlflh6z%40hjp.at) you can do `select * from foos limit 0 \g (format=csv)` and get a string of column names from which you can remove the `id` column and then use in the `COPY` command. This assumes the column order is the same the CSV file as  in the table.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to declare clear columns name without `id` primary key by [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command

> For COPY FROM, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column. Table columns not specified in the COPY FROM column list will receive their default values.

```
COPY foos ( column_name [, ...])
```

Comment: I would need to set 40 column names, just to skip one

Comment: @DevonDahon I don't think there is a way can set all columns except one without declaring clear columns.

Comment: If you want to simplify your writing columns work we can use `information_schema.columns` with `STRING_AGG` function to auto-create those columns.